# On adding cordova-plugin-admob-free@0.27.0, app install successfully but crashes on android device after installation

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

We are using **cordova-plugin-admob-free** latest version in the app. After adding the plugin app crashes on android device.
App build and installed successfully on device but crashes on opening.

**Version details:**
Ionic - 6.10.1
cordova - 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
"cordova-android": "^9.0.0",

**Admob plugin details:**
"cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.27.0",
"cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.24.1",
"@ionic-native/admob-free": "^5.31.1",

**Firebasex plugin verion:**
"cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^11.0.3"

I have tried multiple solutions but no luck. Please help.

Comment: can you added `google-services.json` file in android/app ??

Comment: yes, we added google-services.json in android/app but its still crashing on android device

Comment: Can you share logs?? from android studio.

Comment: It seems there is some issue using plugins cordova-plugin-firebasex and cordova-plugin-admob-free together. Only one of them is working fine at a time.There are some conflicting dependencies, we are not able to resolve.